# record script via a direct connection using LoadRunner

Tags: scripting, loadrunner

I recently started working in LoadRunner 9.0, and I usually record scripts using a proxy connection. But recently I was asked to test the site using a direct connection. I've changed the proxy settings to No-proxy in run-time settings.

But now when I try to record the script, the website takes a long time to load. When the site is browsed with no proxy settings it loads perfectly(quickly). What seems to be the issue here? Do I need to change any other settings?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using the Web based VUser type when you are recording.

The 1st thing to realize is that the recording is done through Internet Explorer (most cases) and it is the IE Proxy settings you have active during recording. Your VuGen Run-Time Settings do not matter during the record, they only have affect during script execution.

If you want to investigate settings for the recording (that do affect the way things are recorded) you can go to recording options (In VuGen: Tools->Recording options) and select the Port Mapping part. Here you can play with many options if you add a new entry.

*Note: I suggest you "write down" the default settings you have prior to playing with the recording options, because you may end up with a non-usable recording set!*

To answer your question; Yes you need to change the IE Proxy Settings to affect the proxy during recording.

I hope this helps,
Kim